# rewrite rule to remove folders in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

when it come to ht-access, i am not very good at this. i tried reading but cant understand it well

i have my website: http://www.website.com/folder1/folder2/param

and i need to rewrite it into: http://www.website.com/folder2/param

can anybody help me with this and tell me what each line is actually doing.
i need to rewrite only if folder2 is the next folder and not other folders
so:
/folder1/folderxxx/param

will remain as it is.

i did this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([a-z]+)/folder1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/folder1/ [L]
```

and when i go to www.website.com/folder.php i get the page but i don't need the .php and if i remove it it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1
RewriteRule ^folder2/(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/$1 [L]
```

And you may need this to *remove* it from the URL in the browser's locaiton bar:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /folder1/folder2
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/(.*)$ /folder2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i tried this and i am getting
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@svn.recruiter.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @user2707590 do you have mod_rewrite loaded? Do you have the proper overrides for htaccess files? (need `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All` in your vhost config). Check the error logs to see what's causing the error

Comment: i fixed this error you typed rewrite wrong... but now i am getting another error in firebug, the status code is 302 found and my website redirect me on 404.html

Comment: i did this: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([a-z]+)/folder1.php`, 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1.php$`, 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/folder1/ [L]` and when i go to `www.website.com/folder.php` i get the page but i dont need the `.php` and if i remove it it doesnt work